# Сравнить 2 строки и вернуть третью с нужним набором слов

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с файлами (`Files`). В ней хранятся как шаблоны документов так и згенерированные на основе шаблонов документы.
В таблице `DocumentTemplates` сохраняются шаблоны.

Пример названий документов:

Название документа-шаблона: `Document Template Symple.docx`
Название згенерированного документа: `17602-Document Template Symple-new_n-20180320.pdf`

Имея 2 этих имени мне нужно получить строку, которая будет содержать часть того, что следует после названия документа-шаблона, в данном случае `new_n`

Как лучше это сделать?

Replace почему-то не работает...

```
SELECT
generatedFile.FileName AS "GeneratedFileName",
( SELECT Files.FileName
  FROM Files
  WHERE Files.Id = DocumentTemplates.FileId
) AS "InitialFileName",
REPLACE(generatedFile.FileName,
( SELECT Files.FileName
  FROM Files
  WHERE Files.Id = DocumentTemplates.FileId
),'') AS "NeededName"
FROM WorkDocuments
JOIN DocumentTemplates ON WorkDocuments.SourceDocumentTemplateId = DocumentTemplates.Id
JOIN Files generatedFile ON generatedFile.Id = WorkDocuments.FileId
```

Или скажите куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для приведенного примера получился вот такой код

```
DECLARE @doc nvarchar(max);
SET @doc='Document Template Symple.docx';

DECLARE @genDoc nvarchar(max);
SET @genDoc='17602-Document Template Symple-new_n-20180320.pdf';

DECLARE @lengthDoc int = LEN(@doc) - 4;

DECLARE @result nvarchar(max);
SET @result = SUBSTRING(@genDoc, CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@doc, 0, @lengthDoc), @genDoc) + @lengthDoc, LEN(@genDoc));
SET @result = SUBSTRING(@result, 0, CHARINDEX('-', @result))
SELECT @result;
```

Если это объединить в одно выражение, то получается вот такая "бяка"

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@genDoc, CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@doc, 0, LEN(@doc) - 4), @genDoc) + LEN(@doc) - 4, LEN(@genDoc)), 0, CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(@genDoc, CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@doc, 0, LEN(@doc) - 4), @genDoc) + LEN(@doc) - 4, LEN(@genDoc))))
```

Comment: Супер! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Пжлста. Я думаю, это не идеальное решение. Вероятно можно попробовать еще через PATINDEX реализовать, корректно составив выражение символ-шаблона.